# AuthGuard not working while refreshing the page

Tags: angular

My Authguard looks like below.

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService,
              private router: Router) {

    }

  
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.accountService.currentUser$.pipe(
        map(auth => {
          if (auth) {
            return true;
          }
          this.router.navigate(['pages/login'], {queryParams: {returnUrl: state.url}});
        })
      );
  }
}
```

account service

```
export class AccountService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUserToken>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
     
  }

  loadCurrentUser(token: string) {
    if (token === null) {
      this.currentUserSource.next(null);
      return of(null);
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    return this.http.get(this.baseUrl + 'user/current', { headers }).pipe(
      map((user: IUserToken) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        this.currentUserSource.next(user);
      })
    );
  }
```

in appcomponent.ts file.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'AdyaNew';

  constructor(
    private accountService: AccountService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadCurrentUser();
  }

  loadCurrentUser() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log(token);
    this.accountService.loadCurrentUser(token).subscribe(
      () => {
        console.log('Loaded user');
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

In my accountrouting

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AccountComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Account' }
  },
  {
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    path: 'checkout',
    component: CheckoutComponent,
    data: { breadcrumb: 'Checkout' }
  },
```

The above code working fine while going into checkout. However while refreshing the checkout component, it is just returning the blank page. Looks like authguard is keep waiting for the currentusersource observable value. Kindly help me out what is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle refresh page, you shouldn't use `AppComponent#ngOnInit` method. Use `APP_INITIALIZER` providers to do it. You want to load user (if any logged) before application starts. There is tons of samples avaiable but you have to convert `Observable` into `Promise`.

 https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER